Enhance the SAPUI5 About Dialog
Is there a possibility to enhance the "About" dialog of a SAPUI5 app and to display an additional attribute?

I have tried to use the standard view extensions but I didn't find an example in github.com.

I don't think the About Dialog is extensible. But sounds like a good idea to me. Consider asking for an enhancement in FLP as per the KBA 2469897 - How to submit a feature request for Fiori launchpad.
